# getting Null value when trying to save user data to userDefaults

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, alamofire, nsuserdefaults

I have a login view Controller which uses firebase to login using user's mobile phone number, and from this login and using the phone number I am trying to pull the user Role from my server, but it always give me null and empty data

userphone var

```
    var UserPhonevar = ""
```

Get user data func

```
   func getUserData() {
    let url = "xyz.com/apis/getprofile.php?mob=" + UserPhonevar
    AF.request(url).validate().responseJSON { [self] response in
        switch response.result
        {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .success(let value):

            let json = JSON(value)
            if let id = json["data"]["id"].string {
                print("id: \(id)")
            }
            self.accountDetails["name"] = json["data"]["name"].string
            self.accountDetails["email"] = json["data"]["email"].string
            self.accountDetails["phone"] = json["data"]["phone"].string
            self.accountDetails["role"] = json["data"]["role"].string
        }
}
   

 }
```

Login button action

```
    @IBAction func OTP_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let otptxt = OTPtxt.text else { return }
    guard let verificationId = def.string(forKey: "verificationId") else { return }
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID:verificationId ,verificationCode: otptxt)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { [self]success, error in
        if error == nil{
            var userPhone = success?.user.phoneNumber
            let prefix = "+966" // What ever you want may be an array and step thru it
            guard userPhone!.hasPrefix(prefix) else { return }
            userPhone = String(userPhone!.dropFirst(prefix.count).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.setValue(userPhone, forKey: "phone")
                print("UserPhon is: \(userPhone)")
            self.UserPhonevar = userPhone!
            getUserData()
            let userRole = self.accountDetails["role"]
            defaults.setValue(userRole, forKey: "role")
            print("UserRole is: \(userRole)")
            print("Success User Can Log in")
            if let deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState() {
                let userId = deviceState.userId
                self.userToken = userId!
             }
            API.GetUsrID(mobile: userPhone!, token: self.userToken) { (error: Error?, success: Bool) in
                if success {
                    print("User")
                    //put thing in this??? save user id
                    let id = Helper.getUserId()
                   print("id: \(id)")
                   if Helper.getUserId() != nil {
                       //skip login and open the main page
   } else {
           //            //Take use to complete registration

                } else {
                    print("success is false")
                }
                if let erro = error {
                    print(erro.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }else {
            print( "Error \(error?.localizedDescription)" )
        }
    
})
}
```

Comment: `getUserData()` works asynchronously. You have to add a completion handler. I just marked a [question as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66059501/alamofire-response-delay-issue) with a similar issue. And don't use `setValue(_:forKey)` in `UserDefaults` unless you know what KVC is and you mean KVC.

Answer (score 0):

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092192/keep-contents-of-a-textfield-visible-after-going-back-and-forwards-in-navigation/66100384#66100384) I am doing same getting response and storing it inside User Default