# Keep contents of a textfield visible after going back and forwards in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a little problem. I'm using a navigation controller and textfields in my different views. My problem is when I go backwards with the back button and then go forwards, the text fields get erased. I would like to keep the content of the text field visible in this case. Is there an option for this?

Thank you for your help and feel free to ask a question if I wasn't clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

It will stay visible until you terminate your app but still if thats not working
inside your viewWillAppear wrtie this

get data from userDefault :

```
if let name = Constants.kUserDefaults.string(forKey: appConstants.name){
            self.userName.text = name
        }
        
        if let email = Constants.kUserDefaults.string(forKey: appConstants.email){
            self.userEmail.text = email
        }
```

and to setData on Button click or where you are naviating you controller do this :

```
 Constants.kUserDefaults.set(responseData?["name"], forKey: appConstants.name)  
   
 Constants.kUserDefaults.set(responseData?["email"], forKey: appConstants.email)
```

where contsant is Structure for User defualt:

```
struct Constants {
    
    static let kUserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
 
}
```

This code will work even after you kill your app or even if you run it next day, it will keep working until unless you delete your app from mobile phone.
Do study more about USER DEFAULTS